# Stop executing onClick callback on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to bind a redirect to onClick event in `render` method:

```
render: function () {
   return React.createElement('div', {onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this, '/route')}, 'click me');
},

handleClick: function (route) {
   ReactRouter.browserHistory.push(route);
}
```

The problem is that the redirection is executed on render, and not on click. How should I do this properly?

Comment: the problem is not here but you should have `this.handleClick.bind(this, '/route')}` instead of `this.handleClick.bind(this, '/route'}`

Comment: Are you sure this is actually your problem? The handleClick function in your example wouldn't get called on render. Also, in this example, the binding of this isn't necessary.

Comment: easiest way to start react is with some starter kit,  you can build build every thing on your own oe you can start with facebooks' starter kit, check this link for more https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html